# generating a password for login instead of a token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, forgot-password, devise-recoverable

I'm new to Devise.

I want that when a user clicks on forgot password link, he should get an email with an auto generated password which a user can use for login in my app, or even get both the auto generated password and a token to reset the password.

I have looked at Devise's passwords controller but wasn't sure what to do.

```rb
  # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
  def edit
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    set_minimum_password_length
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
  end
```

I have also looked at this code below but still am failing on how I can implement it.

```rb
def send_reset_password_instructions
  token = set_reset_password_token
  send_reset_password_instructions_notification(token)
  token
end
```

Comment: This does not answer your question, but ... please, for the love of all things secure, do not do this. Do not even contemplate doing this. Then after you've abandoned this idea, proselytize to others about how abjectly wrong it is to ever think about doing this.

Comment: thanks for the advise. but am learning and i just imagined being tasked to that on my first job. great idea bro

Comment: A more important skill is to learn to just evaluate ideas before you try to put them into practice. If you were tasked with this what you really need to know is how to push back and explain why this is a bad idea in way that doesn't create conflict - not how to cobble together a fatal security flaw.

Comment: thanks guys. but can anyone try to explain more to me how bad it is, such that i get to more about what i was going to mess around